# somar valores em subquery por campo

Tags: mysql

bom dia, estou tentando resolver isso mas não consigo, nesse *select* ele tem um campo chamado `emprestimo_id`. Preciso somar o valor restante de cada empréstimo numa *subquery* chamada "*restante*", porém o que acontece é que ele soma o valor de todos os empréstimos. Preciso que mostre apenas a soma de cada número de empréstimo.

```
SELECT 
    id,
    valor,
    data_pagamento,
    (SELECT nome_fantasia FROM clientes WHERE id = cliente_id) as cliente,
    (SELECT observacoes FROM clientes WHERE id = cliente_id) as observacoes,
    (SELECT CONCAT(endereco, ' N: ',numero ) FROM clientes WHERE id = cliente_id) as endereco,
    data_recebimento,
    prazo,
    cliente_id,
    emprestimo_id,
    valor_pago,
    forma_pagamento,
    (SELECT (SELECT parcelas * valor_parcela FROM emprestimo WHERE id = emprestimo_id) - SUM(valor_pago) as saldo_devedor FROM parcelas WHERE emprestimo_id = emprestimo_id AND juros != 'sim' ) as restante
FROM 
    parcelas
WHERE data_pagamento BETWEEN 20210505 AND 20210505 AND emprestimo_id NOT IN (SELECT renegociacao FROM emprestimo WHERE cliente_id = cliente_id) AND emprestimo_id IN (SELECT id FROM emprestimo WHERE quitado != 'sim' AND cliente_id IN (SELECT id FROM clientes WHERE forma_pagamento = 'DINHEIRO' AND usuario_cobranca = 'FULANO'))
```

Comment: olha só olhar para a query, que por sinal já é bem complicada, tem 3 select in aninhados que pode dar problemas de performance, mas isso é outro ponto, então fica difícil ajudar, seria mais fácil se colocasse exemplo dos dados, de como está retornando e como seria o esperado

Answer (score 0):

> Preciso somar o valor restante de cada empréstimo numa subquery
> chamada "restante", porém o que acontece é que ele soma o valor de
> todos os empréstimos. Preciso que mostre apenas a soma de cada número
> de empréstimo.

Vamos isolar a subconsulta chamada "restante", formatando-a para facilitar a leitura.

> ```
> (         
>   select (select parcelas * valor_parcela
>             from emprestimo
>            where id = emprestimo_id) - SUM(valor_pago) as saldo_devedor
>     from parcelas          
>    where emprestimo_id = emprestimo_id
>      and juros != 'sim'   
> ) as restante
> ```

O problema é que no `where` está `emprestimo_id = emprestimo_id`. É necessário referenciar o `emprestimo_id` da consulta principal.

### **Solução**

Sugiro que no `FROM parcelas` crie um aliasse ficando `FROM parcelas p` e então na subconsulta você irá referenciar o `p` ficando da seguinte forma:

```
(
    select (select parcelas * valor_parcela
              from emprestimo
             where id = emprestimo_id) - SUM(valor_pago) as saldo_devedor
      from parcelas
     where emprestimo_id = p.emprestimo_id
       and juros != 'sim' 
) as restante
```

Desta forma, a subconsulta deve retornar o valor por cada empréstimo.

### **Outro ponto de atenção:**

```
  AND emprestimo_id NOT IN (SELECT renegociacao 
                              FROM emprestimo 
                             WHERE cliente_id = cliente_id)
```

Acredito que aqui também deva referenciar a consulta principal `p`:

```
  AND emprestimo_id NOT IN (SELECT renegociacao 
                              FROM emprestimo 
                             WHERE cliente_id = p.cliente_id)
```

Em regra, se a subconsulta deve fazer um cálculo específico de um registro da `consulta principal` que esteja sendo "processado" pelo banco de dados, essa subconsulta deve referenciar um campo da consulta principal. Quando não faz dessa forma, é como se no seu `where` não resultasse diferença alguma no comando SQL, pois é como se o `cliente_id = cliente_id` estivesse `1 = 1` ou `2 = 2` etc, pois o campo está referenciando a si próprio e não a uma *variável* externa.

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda, deu certo essa dica de colocar um alias no FROM da parcela